# TS2304: Cannot find name '__decorate' , '__metadata' and '__extends'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I am trying to integrate Karma and Jasmine for my angular application which is currently at `v4.1.3` with `TypeScript@2.3.0` and using `@types`. This question is not a duplicate of other `TS2304` errors because I am not facing issues with 'require' or 'process' etc...

When I run `npm test` , I get the following errors in a bunch of component files,

```
Cannot find name '__metadata'.
Cannot find name '__decorate'.
Cannot find name '__extends'.
```

tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib" : ["es2015.core", "es6", "es7", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "allowJs" : true,
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "jquery",
      "lodash",
      "moment",
      "node"
  ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
  "typings"
],

"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
"resolveGlobs": true,
"forkChecker": true
},
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

When i try to search for the names, i don't find them in the `.ts` files. Where is this error generated from? Is it from bundled js?

Comment: It's still a duplicate. That the names of what is not being found are different is irrelevant. If a question asks about adding two integer variables named C and D, it's still a duplicate of the same question asking how to add A and B; it's not different just because the variable names are different.

Answer (score 1):

Those functions are compiler helpers. You have `"noEmitHelpers": true` which disable their generations causing errors.
[TypeScript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)